# Why are interfaces not allowed as annotation members?

Tags: java, types, interface, annotations, default

Consider this code:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Bar {
    Foo foo() default FooImpl.FooConstant;
}
```

Compiler error:

> annotation value not of an allowable type

If I replace `Foo` with `FooImpl` the code is accepted.

What's the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I replace Foo with FooImpl the code is accepted.

I would be very surprised if this compiled, unless FooImpl is an enum.

Annotation members may only contain the following:

- primitive type
- String
- Class literal
- annotation
- enum item
- or 1-dimensional arrays of any of the above

> It is a compile-time error if the return type of a method declared in
>   an annotation type is any type other than one of the following: one of
>   the primitive types, String, Class and any invocation of Class, an
>   enum type (§8.9), an annotation type, or an array (§10) of one of the
>   preceding types. It is also a compile-time error if any method
>   declared in an annotation type has a signature that is
>   override-equivalent to that of any public or protected method declared
>   in class Object or in the interface annotation.Annotation.

Source: [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.7)

Answer (score 3):

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.7

The annotation member types must be one of: primitive, String, Class, an Enum, an array of any of the above

It is a compile-time error if the element type is not commensurate with the ElementValue.

Hope this helps!

Found the same in this documentation as well:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html

"Return types are restricted to primitives, String, Class, enums, annotations, and arrays of the preceding types." As mentioned "interface" is not allowed.

Comment: I fulfill the first sentence, the second one seems to be the problem. I wonder why this is not allowed in annotations ...

Comment: @soc *I fulfill the first sentence* No you don't. `Class<? extends Foo> fooType()` would be valid, `Foo foo()` isn't.

Comment: consider Foo Foo() as a method (just for the sake of simplicity)... can we mention interface as return type for a method ??? :)