# How to return an object in a Java annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

I am making a Test annotation, and I want to be able for the user to specify an expected return value.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Test {
    Object value() default null;
    Class<? extends Throwable> exception() default NoException.class;
    int timeout() default 0;
}
```

As I know, you cannot specify *Object* as the return type in annotation methods.

I am wondering if there is a return type which allows primitives AND strings to be returned.

If not, is it possible to create? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are interfaces not allowed as annotation members?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161190/why-are-interfaces-not-allowed-as-annotation-members)

Comment: You can not. See comment for explanation. Besides that what is the point of returning value ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short no. The oracle docs explain this

> Return types are restricted to primitives, String, Class, enums, annotations, and arrays of the preceding types. Methods can have default values

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html) for the Oracle documents on this.

If you could pass an object what would be the syntax? The items that are passed have to be constants which is why there is the restriction

Comment: Question clearly specifies that he wants "primitives AND strings". So no class instances (other than Strings). I agree that it should be possible somehow. Too bad..